# Can you upgrade the walls in existing buildings?

Tags: steam, 7-days-to-die, war-of-the-walkers, alpha-20

I'm using a farm house as my home base and am trying to upgrade the exterior doors and walls. I was able to upgrade the exterior doors. When I point the upgrade tool (nail gun in this case) at a wall, it makes this clanking sound and displays a red X and the icon for wood. I am carrying 500+ wood in my inventory, so I'm wondering if am I able to upgrade the walls?

Edit: attached screenshots showing the nail gun trying to upgrade a wall with the wood icon popup in the lower right, and the second showing 542 wood in my inventory.

[image: nail gun needs wood to upgrade wall]
[image: inventory has 542 wood]

Comment: What system is this and what version of the game are you playing?

Comment: Posting a screenshot of the icon you mentioned as well as the door you are trying to upgrade would help.  If I remember right, it goes wood → raw iron → forged iron → forged steel.

Comment: @Nelson this is Steam with the War of the Walkers mod.  I added those tags, totally forgot to specify them earlier. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the icon being shown for materials I was lacking for upgrading the wood walls is not *Wood*, rather it is *Wood & Nails*. As I continued playing the game, I randomly found this material in a Trader's inventory, so purchased everything they had, and when I returned to my home base was able to upgrade the walls with it.

[image: Wood & Nails Resource]
[image: Upgraded wall in existing POI]

Comment: That must be specific to that mod you are using because I don't recall that being an item in vanilla